# Call variabel in other function codeigniter

Tags: function, codeigniter

My First controller

```
function index(){  
   if (isset($_POST['search'])) {    
      $info['fromdate'] = $this->input->post('fromdate');   
      $info['enddate'] = $this->input->post('enddate');  
      $this->session->set_userdata($info['fromdate'],$info['enddate']);
   }
}
```

My second function is

```
function detail(){

   }
```

My question is, how to call  $info['fromdate'] in to the function detail()

Thanks

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Declare $info as an array outside index function. Or assign it to a variable that is outside index function. More like increasing the scope of the variable.

Comment: Can You explain with some code please.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is nice but index and detail are two different routes, please try below code

```
class A extends CI_Controller {

    public $info = array();

    function __construct(){

        if (isset($_POST['search'])) {  // $this->input->post('search',true);

            $info['fromdate'] = $this->input->post('fromdate');
            $info['enddate'] = $this->input->post('enddate');
            //load session library if haven't
            $this->session->set_userdata($info['fromdate'],$info['enddate']);
        }

    }

    function index(){
        print_r($this->info);
    }

    function detail(){
        print_r($this->info);
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to use `parent::__construct()` just below `function __construct()` as shown here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#class-constructors

Answer (score 0):

you can try returning the needed information and then get it in function details

```
function index(){  
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {    
  $info['fromdate'] = $this->input->post('fromdate');   
  $info['enddate'] = $this->input->post('enddate');  
  $this->session->set_userdata($info['fromdate'],$info['enddate']);

return $this->session->set_userdata($info['fromdate'],$info['enddate']);
}
}

function detail(){
    $this->index();
}
```